# I need to pass XML node to stored procedure for two different excel sheets

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have one workbook having two excel sheets stored in SFTPlocation. I need to read data from excel sheet and convert that data to XML. That XMLwill be passed to stored procedure and will insert that data into table. Its running fine if i am having one sheet in workbook, but this workbook is having two different excel sheet and i need to insert data in single table. when i am reading data from first sheet the XML i am getting is like this

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Sheet1>
 </Sheet1>
 <Sheet1>
 </Sheet1>
</NewDataSet>
```

so i use stored procedure where i need to pass the XML node of above XML. It is like this where i am passing NewDataSet/Sheet1

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
'Product' = x.v.value('Product[1]','nvarchar(50)')
into #TempTable
from @XMLDataRecord.nodes('NewDataSet/Sheet1') x(v)
```

so this is whole procedure for first sheet.
When i am reading from second sheet the XML i am getting is

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Sheet2>
 </Sheet2>
 <Sheet2>
 </Sheet2>
</NewDataSet>
```

now when this XML will be passed to stored procedure i need to pass XML node of this XML to Stored Procedure as NewDataSet/Sheet2. The problem is How i will pass NewDataSet/Sheet2 in stored Procedure in which i should take NewDataSet/Sheet1 for first time and then NewDataSet/Sheet2 second time dynamically.

Comment: when you are getting XML from sheet2 in string.you can use string replace and replace "sheet2" with "sheet1".like this   
||string temp = xml.Replace("sheet1", "sheet2")||
We need a new variable temp as strings are immutable.

Comment: thanks.hey it worked.You post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

when you are getting XML from sheet2 in string.you can use string replace and replace "sheet2" with "sheet1".like this ||string temp = xml.Replace("sheet1", "sheet2")|| We need a new variable temp as strings are immutable.